# Flattening the intersection of overlapping spheres

Tags: modeling, mesh

as everybody know, when you put two spheres close to each other  they intersect other like this :

[image]

How do I flatten the spheres at the region where they intersect each, I tried to illustrate this with a quickdraw :[image]

I don't know if it's possible with physics like soft body or collision.
does anyone know how to get this result,  i need this for a still image not for animation.

I'm more looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: This works but i want the effect even when i'm note playing the animation, i need this for a fix image not for animation, is there a way to get the physics result in one frame ?

Comment: This is for a personal project and i have absolutely no dead line, so do it only if you got the time, thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bmesh script**

Script to flatten spheres on their intersection plane. See intersection of two spheres on [Paul Bourke's magnificent geometry site](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) The code runs through each selected sphere, checks if they intersect, if they do clalculates the location of the circle of hit.

If there's a collision, for both spheres, selects all vertices that are within the conic angle of the collision and moves them to the point of intersection with the collision disc.  NOTE: script relies on the origin of the spheres being the (default) centre of geometry.

[image: Sphere example]
*Test run on UV Spheres.*

**The script**

Select all the spheres you want to modify and run script. Alter the `scale` to change the angle of effect of flattening vertices.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import acos, degrees, radians
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_line_plane
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
spheres = [(o, max(axis for axis in o.dimensions) / 2) for o in context.selected_objects]
bmeshes = {}

scale = 1.0 # alter to widen bump angle.
def new_bmesh(me):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(me)
    return bm

def squish(sphere, angle, global_plane_co, global_plane_no):
    mw = sphere.matrix_world
    mwi = mw.inverted()

    bm = bmeshes.setdefault(sphere.name, new_bmesh(sphere.data))
    local_p = mwi * global_plane_co
    local_norm = mwi * (global_plane_co + global_plane_no) - local_p
    # select all verts via angle
    proj = angle > radians(90)
    if proj:
        angle = radians(180) - angle
        verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.co.angle(local_p) > angle]
    else:
        verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.co.angle(local_p) < angle]
    for v in verts:
        v.select = True
        d = local_norm if proj else v.co
        o = v.co if proj else Vector()
        hit = intersect_line_plane(o, d, local_p, local_norm)
        if hit and hit.length < v.co.length:
            v.co = hit

while spheres:
    sphere, R = spheres.pop()
    P = sphere.matrix_world.translation    
    for s, r in spheres:        
        p = s.matrix_world.translation
        v = (p - P)
        d = v.length
        v.normalize()
        if d >= r + R:
            continue
        elif abs(r - R) > d:
            continue
        elif d < 0.0001:
            continue

        x = (d * d - r * r + R * R) / (2 * d)
        # define plane
        pt = P + x * v
        norm = v  
        angle1 = acos(x / R)
        angle2 = acos((d - x) / r)
        #print(R, r, x, degrees(angle1), degrees(angle2))
        squish(sphere, scale * angle1, pt, norm)
        squish(s, scale * angle2, pt, norm)

for name, bm in bmeshes.items():
    me = scene.objects[name].data
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()

scene.update()
```

[image: Sample run icospheres]
*Sample run on icosphere cluster on left, result on right*

EDIT: fix for inside cases, now projects back onto plane if hit is inside (angle is greater than 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for, i try it as soon as possible, thank you for your answer batFINGER

Comment: @amby given this comment, I've edited your question.  Re-edit it if it's not your intention.

Comment: it was my intention, i just have some trouble to explain my idea in english (i'm french), so i make lots of mistakes in english..

Comment: @amby edited script to handle inside cases better.

Answer (score 3):

If i understood the question maybe your looking for this

I have added 2 sphere and to 1 i have added the cast modifier

With the reference of pencil drawing sphere to deform when they touch each other.

In the cast modifier you can play with the settings and get the effect.

[image]