# How to model a jackfruit?

Tags: modeling

I have tried numerous methods to create jack fruit, and all failed.

Method 1: Use voronoi texture as displacement.
Problem: It is creating overlapping bumps.

Method 2: Use tissue addon.
Problem: It creates symmetrical bumps and it is not seamless.

Method 3: Create a basic shape, subdivide it. Extrude individual faces.
Problem: Again, it creates identical bumps and is weird around the edges.

Method 4: hand modeling the skin and shrinkwraping it.
Problem: It is too tiresome and the shrinkwrap is also causing the bumps to stick to the surface of the reference shape. :(

What is the best method to create a realistic jack fruit?

Comment: Check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92271/flattening-the-intersection-of-overlapping-spheres

Comment: It would be good if you could include some reference images of what you’re trying to achieve, highlighting the particular properties of the jack fruit you are trying to replicate that you’re having trouble reproducing. This would help others to be able understand your question even if not familiar with the fruit.

Comment: Use a hair particle system, create a few of the bumps in a group to use as the particles then the random of the hair system should be able to fill in the details in a non uniform manner.