# Accurate modeling of a sessile drops (like dew droplets)

Tags: modeling, particles, fluid-simulation, meta-objects

Is there some relatively easy way to generate drops, like dew, on a given object/scene? I'm interested in some kind of real simulation of fluid-surface interaction (would like to specify surface tension / contact angle for droplets), not just handmade flattened sphere drops such as in many tutorials.

Comment: This one could help you a bit: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92271/flattening-the-intersection-of-overlapping-spheres and for the rest of your question, no it's not possible "out-of-the-box" in Blender. I don't think that even Mantaflow will have surface tension in it.

Comment: I have no clue how it would turn out, but try making the object a fluid input via mesh. If you leave no velocity, the water should bubble up on the edge of the item. Just an idea :D